# Recycler View height relative to screen size

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a `vertical RecyclerView` with some nested `horizontal RecyclerViews`, each of which containing images. The height of the `horizontal RecyclerView` is wrap_content, so relative to the size of the images (50x75).
How can I set the height of the `RecyclerView` (or the images) relative to the screen size? I tried with weightSum and `layout_weight` but it doesn't work.

Horizontal RecyclerView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/topten_border_top"
        android:padding="2dp">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/itemTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Sample title"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp" />


    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/topten_border_top"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Content of the horizontal RecyclerView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.rese.biblioteca_3.MainActivity"
    android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="0dp"
    >      <!-- * -->

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"

        android:background="#00000000"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        app:srcCompat="@android:color/darker_gray" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/imageButton"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="18sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: you want horizontal recycler view items to cover the whole screen ?Can you give a screenshot of what you want ?

Comment: Look at the homepage of the Play Store; I want something like this. The size of the app image must not be specified (e.g. 50x75 px) but relative to the screen size, so that if I open the app on a tablet I see larger icons

Answer (score 0):

You will need to specify the image height and width , since there are textviews in layout as well . To get the play store type horizontal recycler view do this :

In your `content of horizontal recycler view` make height and width wrap_content:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:padding="0dp"
  >
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: So I have to save images at different sizes for different screens? Like the mipmap folder have different sized icons? (hdpi, mdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi, xxxhdpi)

Comment: Android selects which alternative resource to use at runtime, depending on the current device configuration. So you can also have only hdpi and it will work. To read more about this : https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#BestMatch